# JQuery- How to useing ALS scrolling script for images?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to using [ALS](http://als.musings.it/) to scrolling some image automatically,But my image size are different form ALS script default images and when i try it everything was falling apart.
do you know any simpler and good way to make images auto scrolling like ALS script ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally like Slick. It's easy to modify too. http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/
Deals well with variable sizes and you can have it automatically scroll through the images.

Answer (score 1):

**CSS:**

```
.als-item img { max-width: 128px; }
```

**jQuery:**

```
$("#my-als-list").als({
    autoscroll: "yes"
});
```

Comment: Thnak you,That's help me to fix some of my problems,But finally i decide to using "Slick" As @Charlie L said.it's seems so awesome script.

Comment: You're welcome. Als looks very simple. Slick is good, but take a look to bxslider too (http://bxslider.com/options), very nice, configurable slider.